# Find distinct value using LokiJS?

Tags: lokijs

Is there any way to find distinct value like using mongo command `db.collection.distinct()` using lokiJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built facility to get distinct values at the moment, so at the moment you would have to iterate a `ResultSet` or `DynamicView` to work that out, which should be pretty easy:

```
let dist = [];
view.forEach((elem) => {
  if (dist.indexOf(elem) === -1) {
    dist.push(elem);
  }
});
return dist;
```

I can open an issue on github so the feature gets implemented if you want, as it sounds interesting.

Comment: Yes please open and issue in github. This feature is one of the basics.

Comment: As of 1/02/2018 this isn't done yet. Link to SO post: https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/issues/373